# MVC4 - AuthConfig.cs missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to get started with the OpenAuth features of MVC4 as described here:

http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m7-security&mode=live&clip=9&course=mvc4-building

I already did start over again a couple of times in order not to miss anything, but even though I am choosing the right template (Internet Application) there is no AuthConfig.cs.

Nor do I find documentation what to do to get the required tasks done manually. 
I am pretty sure this is a pretty dumb question, but maybe I don't find the answer because it is so obvious... 
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unbelievable.. I used the RC Version of Visual Studio and even though I reinstalled MVC4 from scratch the recent version including the openauth extensions wasn't properly available.

Following the same steps on the regular Visual Studio Installation did the trick...

Answer (score 2):

I followed these steps:

Open File/New/Project

Select ASP.NET MVC 4 web Application

Then Select internet Application

Once the project was created there should be a AuthConfig.cs file within App_Start folder

Comment: that's what I did multiple times. without success. The App_Start folder contains all the configs, but the AuthConfig...

Comment: Maybe you don't have dotnetopenauth package. Open ManageNuGetPackages, and see if it's there, if not search it and install it. Check https://nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth